# Anko equivalent to style attr in xml

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I need to create borderless button. The easyest way in xml to set `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless`. I'm trying to do this using `Anko`

```
button(theme = R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless_Colored, text = "Send") {
    horizontalGravity = Gravity.END
    lparams(wrapContent, wrapContent)
}
```

But there is no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using third constructor parameter, which accepts `attr` resource:

```
addView(Button(activity, null, R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle))
```

Also, you can declare it as a DSL component:

```
fun ViewManager.borderlessButton(textRes: Int = 0) =
        borderlessButton(textRes) { }

fun ViewManager.borderlessButton(textRes: Int = 0, init: Button.()->Unit) =
        ankoView({ Button(it, null, R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle) }, 0) {
            if (textRes != 0) setText(textRes)
            init()
        }
```

Then, your call-site may look like this:

```
borderlessButton(android.R.string.ok)
```

You may look at Anko's `horizontalProgressBar` method and [`HORIZONTAL_PROGRESS_BAR_FACRTORY`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/cd2b30d0dc54ff8998a1c3a2159967515ac45498/anko/library/static/platform/src/CustomViews.kt#L41) which are declared in similar way.

Answer (score -1):

The order is wrong. Try this:

```
button("Your text", android.support.design.R.style.Base_Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless_Colored) {
  //your params
 }
```

This works for me.

Comment: Kotlin's got named parametres, no need to keep the order if you name them (as in the question)